# Selectively Iterate over Tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently building a CNN with Keras and need to define a custom loss function. I would only like to consider specific parts of my data in the loss and ignore others based on a certain parameter value. But, I am having trouble iterating over the Tensor objects that the Keras loss function expects.

**Is there a simple way for me to compute the mean squared error between two Tensors, only looking at selected values in the Tensor?**

For example, each Tensor in my case represents a 2D 16x16 grid, with each cell having 2 parameters - shape (16, 16, 2). I only want to compare cells where one of their parameters is equal to 1.

Comment: For each sample in each batch, do you know beforehand (i.e. when that batch is passed on to the network) which parts of the output tensors you should ignore or those you want to mask?

Comment: Yes, I can tell from my inputs (which are the same shape) where I am going to ignore cells.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to use binary masks. Tensorflow provides several boolean functions such as `tf.equal` and `tf.not_equal`. For selecting only enterings which are equal to a certain value, you could use `tf.equal` and then multiply the loss tensor by the obtained binary mask.